# Is there a way to populate a drop-down with the templates files in a folder?

Tags: templating, matrix, drop-down, field

When I have a folder setup for template partials, is there a way I could automatically populate a drop-down with the list of templates in that folder?

This would be useful in the case where I have a complex matrix field set, and would like to select a partial to render or include along with the block's content.

If the drop-down were automatically populated, it would eliminate a lot of time setting up the drop-downs in the backend, and would make it much easier to deploy new feature sets across many Craft based sites as they are developed or improved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using this:

https://github.com/lukeholder/dir

to populate this plugin with the template names:

https://github.com/lewisjenkins/craft-lj-dynamicfields/

Comment: Works great Luke. {% for template in craft.dir.templates('some/folder') %}
  { "value":"{{ template }}" , "label":"{{ template }}" }{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

Comment: thanks @pixelJitsu i still think there is a good market for a template selector field plugin, but this is a good stopgap. :)

Answer (score 6):

This would be a good task for a plugin.

You'd essentially need to build the plugin to do a couple of things:

(1) Use PHP in a **[service](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/services)** to list the contents of a directory. Once you have that list, you'd then need to...

(2) Deliver that information to the front end via a custom **[field type](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/field-types)**. You can then use your new custom field type wherever you'd like.

Comment: Combine

https://github.com/lukeholder/craft-dir

to populate this plugin with the template names:

https://github.com/lewisjenkins/craft-lj-dynamicfields/

Comment: I would love to see a plugin that does a much more sophisticated template picker in the future - maybe even with thumbnails for the different templates.